# How to figure out how many tables are affected in database after inserting a record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

One third party app is storing data in a huge database (SQL Server 2000/2005). This database has more than 80 tables.  How would I come to know that how many tables are affected when application stores a new record in database? Is there something available I can retrieve the list of tables affected?

Comment: I guess it's all in perspective, I would consider 80 tables to be a tiny database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to tell by running a trace in [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929%28SQL.90%29.aspx) on the database - the     [SQL:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886%28SQL.90%29.aspx) event is probably the one to monitor - i.e. if the application does a series of inserts into multiple tables, you should see them go through in Profiler.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQL Profiler to trace SQL queries. So you will see sequence of calls caused by one button click in your application.

Also use can use metadata or SQL tools to get list of triggers which could make a lot of actions on simple insert.

Answer (score 0):

you can add triggers on tables that get fired on update - you could use this to update a log table that would report what was being updated.

see more here: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/Using-Triggers-In-MS-SQL-Server/

Comment: Am i going to add triggers to all 80 tables? Since data is entered by Third party tool, I just need to know when one record is inserted in how many tables out of 80 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Profiler is the way to go, as others have said especially with an unfamilar third party database.

I would also spend some time creating diagrams so you can see the foreign key relationships and understand how the database is put together.  I usaully know my database structure so well, I can tell from the fields being inserted what tables they affect and I know what triggers are on my tables and what they affect. There is no substitute for taking the time to understand the database you support.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SQL script that used to store the new record(Usually, it should be insert statement, or other DML statement such as update, merge and so on). Then you may know how many tables were affected by parsing those SQL script.

Take this SQL for example:

```
Insert into emp(fname, lname)
Values('john', 'reyes')
```

You can get result like this:

```
sstinsert
 emp(tetInsert)

Tables:
emp

Fields:
emp.fname
emp.lname
```